# Knitr hanging on system() call

Tags: r, latex, system, knitr

How do I get knitr to un-hang after running a system call in a chunk? For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Test 

<<>>=
system('"C:\\Program Files\\SASHome\\SASFoundation\\9.3\\sas.exe" "test.sas"')
@

\end{document}
```

This code just hangs forever. By the way, the R code above runs fine. Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, running your code (but substituting in `system("open firefox")`) works just fine for me. Have you played around at all with the chunk options, setting `cache=FALSE`, `results="hide"`, etc.?

Comment: Thanks Josh, I have tried quite a few different knitr chunk options but it still doesn't work. The command system("open firefox") worked for me as well, as well as system("open sas"). This problem seems to be in the host program knowing when the child program has stopped running restarting the original program stream.

Comment: Stupid mistake from my end. I needed to specify the directory of the target code, I was thinking that the .Rnw code was running in the pwd, but it actually references the .Rnw root directory as the pwd. Also found that you can run the command directly in the tex code with \write18{"C:/Program Files/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.3/sas.exe" "C:/dir/test.sas"'}.

Comment: Glad you got that working. You might consider writing up a short answer which you can then (after a couple of days) also accept. Cheers.

Comment: Just FYI, I have added very basic SAS support in the dev version: https://github.com/yihui/knitr See example below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the working directory for the code chunks is the directory of your source document (Rnw doc in this case), so `test.sas` has to be under the same directory with the Rnw file.

Or you can specify the working directory for code chunks with `opts_knit$set(root.dir = '/path/to/desired/dir/')`.

SAS support in `knitr` has been added to the [development version](https://github.com/yihui/knitr), and this is what you can do:

```
<<engine='sas', engine.path="C:\\Program Files\\SASHome\\SASFoundation\\9.3\\sas.exe">>=
/* write the content of your test.sas here */
@
```